# Microsoft Graph API Authorization issue with particular endpoints (e.g. /calendars)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the calendar-related endpoints of the Microsoft Graph API. I've registered my app on Azure AD and configured its application permissions (In fact, I've added the entire list of application permissions for Microsoft Graph API just to make sure at this point)

You can see my access token below, though it's a bit lengthy. jwt.ms also states that it's an Azure AD V1 token.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "AQABAAAAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTfuFEc1xDrKW9OgoxxfapaiuriahgH-pwN7wMt0tMrHmt-nOLiWJm7xzuNTM9Un0NoRzBP_Yor0wOmspcQdql0SAA",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "wULmYfsqdQuWtV_-hxVtDJJZM4Q",
  "kid": "wULmYfsqdQuWtV_-hxVtDJJZM4Q"
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/41dad557-6060-410f-a612-368cf36641f0/",
  "iat": 1541058963,
  "nbf": 1541058963,
  "exp": 1541062863,
  "aio": "42RgYDicbl/RHqaT8XTWla+XJ8j2AgA=",
  "app_displayname": "GraphChatBotTest",
  "appid": "36602029-65b0-44ee-a2bb-f18c0f154969",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/41dad557-6060-410f-a612-368cf36641f0/",
  "oid": "ea391d2a-9e85-4387-99ba-68a28d077a65",
  "roles": [
    "Chat.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
    "Calls.JoinGroupCall.All",
    "EduRoster.Read.All",
    "OnlineMeetings.Read.All",
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All",
    "Device.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
    "SecurityEvents.Read.All",
    "Calendars.Read",
    "EduAssignments.ReadWrite.All",
    "People.Read.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic.All",
    "MailboxSettings.Read",
    "EduAdministration.Read.All",
    "Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Contacts.ReadWrite",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All",
    "Notes.Read.All",
    "User.Invite.All",
    "EduRoster.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "EduAssignments.ReadBasic.All",
    "EduRoster.ReadBasic.All",
    "Files.Read.All",
    "Mail.Read",
    "Chat.Read.All",
    "ChannelMessage.Read.All",
    "EduAssignments.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "identityriskyuser.read.all",
    "EduAdministration.ReadWrite.All",
    "Mail.Send",
    "ChannelMessage.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
    "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
    "Contacts.Read",
    "IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All",
    "AuditLog.Read.All",
    "Member.Read.Hidden",
    "Calls.AccessMedia.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All",
    "Reports.Read.All",
    "Calls.Initiate.All",
    "Notes.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "ea391d2a-9e85-4387-99ba-68a28d077a65",
  "tid": "41dad557-6060-410f-a612-368cf36641f0",
  "uti": "Vy3Z7a_gLEODSO81X4cLAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1487855898
}.[Signature]
```

Now when I use the User and Group endpoints, everything works fine. I can get all users, a specific user and the same applies to groups. However whenever I try to use some other endpoints like /calendars or /events, I get a 401 Unauthorized response, with code "Unknown Error".

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "532d3476-b41b-4d8a-a0ed-b44367c16d7f",
      "date": "2018-11-01T08:19:55"
    }
  }
}
```

For the record, I've tried both the v1.0 endpoints and the beta endpoints, with the same results. According to the API documentation, these endpoints (`/calendars`, `/events`, etc.) should be accessible with the necessary application permissions. What could be the issue here? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Adding sample code to show how I call the API

```
var uri = 
    $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/events";
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Furthermore, when I call the same endpoint from the Graph Explorer (logged in with my own personal account), I get a successful response.

MORE INFO:

When we register an app from the application registration portal (`https://apps.dev.microsoft.com`) instead of azure portal, something funny happens. I can get an access token successfully, but when I use the new app to make the call to `/users`, I get `Authorization_IdentityNotFound` error, whereas when I call `/events` I get `UnknownError`. The application has been granted the following application permissions: `Calendars.ReadWrite`, `User.Read.All`, `Group.Read.All`. Perhaps more importantly, this new app does not show up in the azure portal. Neither for me, nor for the admin. I hope this will shed more light on the issue.

Editing the last edit:

It turns out that the app I created on Application Registration Portal had a different tenant. After changing the tenant id for the `/token` endpoint, I was able to get a successful response when calling `/events` as well as `/users`. Still wondering the root cause of the original issue.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing how you're calling the endpoints? Have you confirmed that the user you are targeting has a provisioned Exchange Online mailbox?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I've added a code sample to the main post. About the Exchange Online mailbox, how can I verify that it does or does not exist? I have no idea.

Comment: Are you able to open the mailbox using [Outlook for the Web](https://outlook.office365.com)?

Comment: Yes, I can access it from the link you provided.

Comment: Have you provided Admin Consent for the app? It looks like it to me but it might be worth doing again. Keep in mind this needs to be done again if you've added additional scopes.

Comment: Yes, we've added every permission (delegated and application) for Microsoft Graph and the application permissions have been granted admin consent (it says "Granted for {OurTenantName}", could it be that we have to get admin consent from a more privileged account? Then again we registered the app as single-tenant). I can't redo it myself since my account is just a regular account, I'll have to wait till tomorrow to do it again.

Comment: Only a Global Admin can grant consent. It only needs to be done once per app, per tenant. I would start by removing _all_ of the Delegated scopes (these don't apply when using `client_credentials`) and only select the Application Scopes `User.Read.All`, `Group.Read.All`, and `Calendars.Read.All`. Selecting "everything" just makes it harder to narrow down what is going sideways.

Comment: We actually started with only the application permissions that we needed (according to the Graph API docs, stuff like Calendar.Read, User.Read.All, etc). When that didn't work, we pretty much granted every possible application permission to the app, alas that also didn't work. It was only after this, that we granted the delegated permissions, because I could call these endpoints successfully via the Graph Explorer, with my own personal account. Anyway, I'll do what you suggested first thing in the morning, but I can't see a permission called "Calendars.Read.All" in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo. `Calendars.Read` is the Application scope (it _would_ be called `Calendars.Read.All` but it predates that convention being adopted).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur We granted the three permissions you mentioned + `Calendars.ReadWrite` (since I want to be able to send a meeting request), but same result, got a 401 when calling `/events`, whereas I can call `/users` and `/groups` successfully.

Comment: You don't need both `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `Calendars.Read`. One if a subset of the other. Are you getting the `401` when creating a new event or just reading existing events?

Comment: We tried only reading so far, with client credentials that is.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I've added some more (hopefully relevant) info to the post.